# How to transition VSCode devcontainers to a production environment?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm a bit of a newb so bear with me.  I'm familiar with writing local applications and scripts to automate admin tasks that I need to do, but now I'm trying to get familiar with the Gitlab CI/CD process.  I have been using (and loving) VSCode devcontainers because I fell into a hole of learning Python virtual environments and trying to manage different python versions, etc., and devcontainers makes all that headache go away for me.  Now I'm trying to figure out how I can write a simple application (like a flask endpoint) and deploy it via Gitlab CI/CD.

I'm currently stuck on how to transition my VSCode Dockerfile for the devcontainer to a production ready Dockerfile.  For instance, the VSCode Dockerfile uses a VSCode base image that I wouldn't imagine would be acceptable in a production environment.  Is there a best practice for creating a production Docker configuration for deployments?  If it is simply a matter of creating a separate Dockerfile, doesn't that defeat one of the purposes of using Docker containers for development?  You would still have a situation of "well it works in my container..."

Comment: I'm facing the same problem moving from devcontainers to production, did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: To be on-topic here, a question should be about a narrow, specific problem. This is a place where different ops and dev teams will negotiate different solutions with different tradeoffs; it's not amenable to a canonical answer, and so not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Yup, someone tried closing it the day it was posted but unfortunately it didn't get enough votes.

Comment: (Personally, I'd argue that Docker is _inherently_ prone to "well, it works in my container"; compare to [Nix](https://nixos.org/) where you can't access any network resources during a build unless you know the exact hash of the content being retrieved -- in the Docker world, containers often have `apt-get update` steps or similar that can pull different versions during different builds, with no record of what happened to be present on the remote servers at any given time).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a best practice for creating a production Docker configuration for deployments?

One of those best practices can be a [Multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/): it allows you to separate the build stage (where you might compile assets, install dependencies, etc.) from the final production stage, which contains only what is necessary to run the application. That approach helps in reducing the size of the final image and improves security by minimizing the attack surface.

- In this first stage, you use a base image that includes all the necessary tools and libraries for compiling and building your application. You install dependencies, compile any assets, and prepare your application.
- The second stage starts with a new, lightweight base image. Here, you copy only the necessary artifacts from the build stage. That stage does not include the extra tools and libraries used for building, making the final image smaller and more secure.

A Dockerfile for a simple Flask application would be:

```
# Stage 1: Build Stage
FROM python:3.9 as builder

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the requirements file
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

# Copy the Flask application
COPY . .

# You can perform any build steps here (e.g., compiling assets)

# Stage 2: Production Stage
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy only the dependencies
COPY --from=builder /root/.local /root/.local

# Copy the built application from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app .

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 5000

# Set environment variables
ENV PATH=/root/.local:$PATH

# Command to run the application
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

The final image contains only your application and its runtime dependencies, not the entire build environment.

You can use the same base image in both your devcontainer and the first stage of your Dockerfile. This ensures consistency in the Python environment across development and build stages.

And use the same `requirements.txt` or an equivalent configuration for dependencies in both environments. In development, you might have additional development-specific packages.