# Is it possible to install devcontainer features in production container builds?

Tags: docker, vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer, open-container-initiative

I make a lot of use of [OCI devcontainer features](https://containers.dev/implementors/features-distribution/) to quickly and easily install an up-to-date stack into devcontainers ([more info in this blog post](https://www.kenmuse.com/blog/intro-to-dev-container-features/)).

But I want my production containers to be built with the same stack (minus the development-specific stuff), and presently I have to manually maintain production dockerfiles to mimic the stack that my devcontainer features install anyway.

How can I build a generic dockerfile such that a specified set of devcontainer features get added to it?

I'm looking for something like

```
docker build --features my_features.json .
```

Is this possible?

This question is inspired by [this post on the python-poetry repo](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/4036) where everyone in the world wants poetry installed to a different base image! A [related but less specific question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70674153/how-to-transition-vscode-devcontainers-to-a-production-environment).

Comment: Being a fan of distroless images and knowing how lazy I am, even if the feature you are looking for exists, I would definitely not use it. It sounds so tempting to use it to install the same stack at the beginning, but losing control on what would be installed on a production image as more features and versions I would depend on.

Comment: Yep, very good point David and well made. For me there's another side of that coin - the territory of very limited human resources maintaining a larger number of environments. It's worth tolerating the bloat in such a case!